# JPG image is not displayed properly on browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, jpeg

I am having a strange issue with displaying JPG image on browser. The image color is mostly washed out while being viewed on any browser (Chrome, IE and FF). But it's fine when using desktop applications (Windows Photo Viewer, Paint, etc.) to view.

You can see the example here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2095747/asp.jpg

Does anyone know any particular reason for it?

Regards,

Harry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image uses a type of embedded [color correction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/ICC_color_correction_in_Firefox) that browsers do not support.

Since you seem to have used Photoshop to generate that image, you should reopen your source file and re-export the image using the "Save for web" action, which will either not embed a color profile at all, or use a browser compatible format.